# Java collections manipulation

Tags: java

1. Is there a better way to add a list to another existing list than what I have coded in the add method ?
2. Is the way to remove a list of songs from a playlist correct or am I going to hit concurrent modification exception ?

   ```
   class Playlist
   {
   List<Song> playList;
   public void addSongs(List<Song> songs)
   {
     for(Song s:songs)
     playList.add(s);
   }

   public void removeSongs(List<Song> songs)
   {
     for(Song s:songs)
     if(playList.contains(s))
     playList.remove(s);
   }


   }
   ```

Comment: I'm creating the playList = new ArrayList .. in the constructor so I'm not going to have null ptr exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add all the elements from one list to another, use;

[`List.addAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29)

> Appends all of the elements in the specified collection to the end of
>   this list, in the order that they are returned by the specified
>   collection's iterator

To remove all the elements from one list from another use;

[`List.removeAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#removeAll%28java.util.Collection%29)

> Removes from this list all of its elements that are contained in the
>   specified collection

Comment: Okay. But what about the way I have coded it ? Does collections API also use the same thing under the hood ?

Comment: @Phoenix You can be sure that it does it better than you do.

Comment: I'm not questioning that. But wondering since this is modification of the list while iterating it does it result in concrrent modification exception

Comment: It will depend upon the implementation, but `ArrayList` automatically resizes it's backing array BEFORE adding new items, meaning it won't suffer from any slow downs as the list tries to increase it's buffer during the add

Comment: @Phoenix You're not iterating from the list your modifying, it will have not impact on it.  List's are not `Thread` safe.  Concurrent modifications could cause a mutation exception. Are you accessing this methods from more then one thread simultaneously??

Comment: @Phoenix - also see my answer about CMEs

Answer (score 2):

In reference to your version of `removeSongs`

> But wondering since this is modification of the list while iterating it does it result in concrrent modification exception

Assuming that the lists are instances of the standard list classes, your code should not throw a CME.

A CME is typically thrown if you modify a collection while iterating it (apart from when you use `Iterator.remove()` ...).  You code is iterating `songs` and modifying `playlist`.  This won't result in a CME in the code shown.

However, if *some other code* is iterating the `playlist` concurrently with this code, *that other code* could get a CME the next time it uses its iterator.  Similarly, if *some other code* modifies `songs` while your code is iterating it, then *this* code could throw a CME.  (You would need to look at the rest of your code to figure out if either of these scenarios is possible.)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `addAll()` and  `removeAll()` methods:

```
playList.addAll(songs);

playList.removeAll(songs);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate your `List`

```
class Playlist
{
List<Song> playList;
public Playlist(){
 playList = new ArrayList<Song>();
}
```

You don't need a loop here. Use `addAll` instead.

```
public void addSongs(List<Song> songs)
{
  playList.addAll(songs);
}
```

You also don't need a loop here. Use `removeAll` instead.

```
public void removeSongs(List<Song> songs)
{
  playList.removeAll(songs);
}


}
```